# Power BI Tooltip Customizability

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Coming from a Tableau background, is there no way to fully customize tooltips in Power BI?

For example, I want all the tooltip to say

> abc

That's it.

Is that not possible?

The closest I've got was:

> new_measure abc

After creating `new_measure = "abc"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't like the default tooltip, you can always create a custom one following the steps below. In your case you may need to customize the tooltip size to be say 50x100, and place a card visual showing a single text measure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-tooltips?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: Even with the Card visual it still shows the measure name under the measure value of "abc". Jesus, why do they make it so hard to customize tooltips?!

Comment: there is always a painful period for picking up a new tool, especially when you used to a different tool. try to make peace with it. I've been developing Tableau reports for a few years before being forced to switch over to PBI. I like it a lot now. To answer your question, you just need to change the card settings.

Comment: Same, tableau gives you so much more freedom from a design point of view.   But alas, company doesn't want it.